# Maximal dimension guaranteed for integral manifolds of hyperplane distributions

Tags: contact-geometry, integrable-systems, tangent-distributions

**To KSackel and anyone else has viewed this:** I'm sorry my edits have been all over the place. I've tried to cut it down to my remaining curiosities, so there's less to wade through (and hopefully fewer mistakes as well).

If $\alpha$ is a non-vanishing 1-form on $\mathbb R^n$ and $M$ is a submanifold tangent to the distribution $\ker\alpha$, then $$\alpha|_{TM}=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad d\alpha|_{TM}=0.$$ Thus if $p\in M$ and $d\alpha|_{\ker \alpha_p}$ has rank $\geq 2r$, then $\text{codim}\,M\leq r+1$ (morally, we lose one dimension to $\alpha$ and $r$ dimensions to $d\alpha$). What about moving in the other direction (i.e. finding submanifolds tangent to the distribution)? If $d\alpha|_{\ker\alpha}$ has constant rank $2r$ near $p$, then we get $$\alpha=dx_1+x_2dx_3+\dots+x_{2r}dx_{2r+1}$$ in some coordinate chart about $p$ (Pfaff-Darboux), so we get an integral manifold of codimension $r+1$ through $p$. But as KSackel points out in the comments, things get complicated without constant rank: we will no longer have a normal form like this, and the rank can decrease on a locus whose codimension is too small to admit larger integral submanifolds. Is it still possible to show that $\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^r=0$ near $p$ implies the existence of an integral manifold through $p$ of codimension $r$?

**Note:** We want to choose the smallest $r$ such that $\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^r=0$ *near* $p$, but there may still be $k<r$ such that $\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^k=0$ *at* $p$. This is the case with KSackel's example $\alpha=dz-y^2dx$. Here, we can find codimension 2 submanifolds, corresponding to the fact that $\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^2=0$.

As a particular case, this would imply that any hyperplane distribution in an $n$-manifold admits integral manifolds of dimension $\text{floor}(n/2)$. I would also be interested in hearing about the higher codimension case of this consequence. If I were to make a guess by strict analogy, I might posit that a $k$-plane bundle on $\mathbb R^n$ admits integral submanifolds through any point of dimension $\text{ciel}(k/2)$. But I've also heard that Pfaffian systems get a whole lot more complicated in codimension $>1$, so maybe not...

Comment: The converse direction isn't true. Consider $\alpha = dz-y^2dx$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is degenerate when $y=0$. Any integral submanifold of dimension $2$ must stay completely within $y=0$ (since $\alpha$ is contact where $y \neq 0$). But then its tangent space always contains $\partial_z$, which is never in $\ker(\alpha)$, so there are no integral submanifolds of dimension $2$ despite $\alpha$ being degenerate. (To have a converse, you would need that the degenerate locus is "large enough" to contain integral submanifolds. Constant rank works, but maybe there's a weaker condition?)

Comment: Thank you, that's a good example. I will update the question to focus on the second half, where I ask if you can replace constancy of rank by upper semicontinuity.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha \wedge d\alpha^{r+1} = 0$ near $p$, and $\alpha \wedge d\alpha^r \neq 0$ at $p$. Then $\alpha \wedge d\alpha^r \neq 0$ near $p$ (by semi-continuity of the rank), and so the rank is constant near $p$. So you can always apply Darboux's solution to the Pfaff problem (what you call Pfaff's problem).

Comment: I agree that in this case, the rank is constant. However, I don't think you can always use such an approach and I added a note about cases where this may not occur.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear: the function $R \colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given as the maximal $r$ such that $\alpha \wedge d\alpha^r \neq 0$, is lower semi-continuous. We may define a corresponding (upper semi-continuous) function $\widetilde{R}$ by $\widetilde{R}(p) := \limsup_{q \rightarrow p}R(q)$. The value of $\widetilde{R}(p)$ tells you that in any arbitrary small neighborhood of $p$, there exists some open region of points $q$ so that $R(q) = \widetilde{R}(p)$, and so you can just find some region of constant rank.

Comment: In particular, if $\alpha \wedge d\alpha^r = 0$ near $p$, then $R(p) < r$ near $p$, and so $\widetilde{R}(p) < r$, from which the conclusion you want follows.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this argument lets us find an integral manifold arbitrarily close to $p$, using the constant-rank argument. But it does not guarantee an integral going through the point $p$ itself, correct?

Comment: Ah, I missed the word "through." No, it does not, as the example shows.